# Function runs forever in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use a function that adds an item to the cart from a detail page to the cart array in the main App component. Whenever the Product Detail component loads, the function runs once and when I click the Add To Cart button, the function runs continuously until React stops the state updating.

Here is my App.js

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cart: []
    };
    this.handleAddToCart = this.handleAddToCart.bind(this);
  }

  handleAddToCart(product) {
    this.setState({
      cart: [this.state.cart, product]
    });
  }
  //I'm using React-Router with history.js
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/product/detail"
            exact
            render={routeProps => (
              <ProductDetail {...routeProps} handleAddToCart={this.handleAddToCart} />
            )}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is ProductDetail.js

```js
class ProductDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      product: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Getting data from React Router Link
    const product = this.props.location.state.product;
    this.setState({
      product: product
    });
  }

  render() {
    const product = this.state.product;
    return (
        <Link onClick={this.props.handleAddToCart(this.state.product)}>
          <Button>
             Add to Cart
          </Button>
        </Link>
    )
  }
}
```

Basically, I only want handleAddToCart to run whenever the button is clicked. Also, I had the button's onClick set to the function, but it wasn't working properly

Comment: Likely unrelated, but you should spread in old cart state array: `this.setState({ cart:[...this.state.cart, product] })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoke it immediately with `this.state.product`, define it as an anonymous callback. You can add an `onClick` handler to the Link, but I think you should have some errors/warnings about a missing `to` prop there.

```
render() {
  const product = this.state.product
  return(
    <Link>
      <Button onClick={() => this.props.handleAddToCart(this.state.product)}>
         Add to Cart
      </Button>
    </Link>
  )
}
```

Comment: @NicholasNorris Negative. `() => callback(...)` !== `callback(...)`. The former waits to be invoked and call the callback, the latter is invoked immediately.